# Rails deploy with capistrano: run sunspot solr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, capistrano3

I'm trying to deploy my rails 4 application with capistrano 3. I've declared all the requirements in gemfile and also added Capfile. I've followed [this gist](https://gist.github.com/imtiaz-emu/dcb87fde71a9562037d2).

My current `deploy.rb` file is looking like:

```
# config valid only for Capistrano 3.1
lock '3.2.1'

set :application, 'my_app_name'
set :repo_url, 'git@github.com:.........'

set :user, 'username'
set :use_sudo, false

# Default branch is :master
# ask :branch, proc { `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.chomp }.call

set :scm, :git

# set :deploy_via, :remote_cache # off while it is first deployment
set :deploy_via, :copy

# Default value for :format is :pretty
# set :format, :pretty
set :rvm1_ruby_version, "ruby-2.1.5"

# Default value for :linked_files is []
set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}

# Default value for linked_dirs is []
set :linked_dirs, %w{log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle}
set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs) + %w{public/system public/uploads}

# Default value for default_env is {}
# set :default_env, { path: "/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH" }

set :pty, true

# Default value for keep_releases is 5
set :keep_releases, 5


# set config unicorn.rb, unicorn_init.sh, nginx.conf file permission after deployment
set :file_permissions_roles, :all
set :file_permissions_users, ['username']
set :file_permissions_chmod_mode, "0777"


namespace :deploy do

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 1 do
      # Your restart mechanism here, for example:
      execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
      # execute "sudo service nginx restart"
      # execute "sudo service unicorn restart"
    end

  end

  desc "reload the database with seed data"
  task :seed do
    run "cd #{current_path}; bundle exec rake db:seed RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env}"
  end

  desc 'Starts SOLR'
  task :reindex do
    run "cd #{current_path} && #{rake} RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} sunspot:solr:reindex"
  end

  before "deploy:updated", "deploy:set_permissions:chmod"

  after :publishing, :restart

  after :restart, :clear_cache do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
      # Here we can do anything such as:
      # within release_path do
      #   execute :rake, 'cache:clear'
      # end
    end
  end

end
```

I've added two tasks (**seed**, **reindex**). But my database doesn't populate with the seed data while I deploy via command `cap production deploy`.
Also, I can't start + reindex my `Solr` dependency.

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Avoid this :

```
"#{rake} RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} sunspot:solr:reindex"
```

Instead write :

```
"RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:reindex"
```

A lot of my issues were solved by switching the RAILS_ENV declaration to the very beginning of the command.

Also, this is the command to reindex Solr indeed, but I fail to see where you start Solr.

To start Solr :

```
RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start
```

But this might fail while telling you it worked fine. If you feel this is the case, you can run this instead :

```
RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:run
```

To execute solr in the current shell. You will then see if there is an issue and the nature of such issue.